# How to pass an enumeration type as parameter of a method?

Tags: delphi

I need to pass an enumeration to a method but I need a generic way to pass the enumeration. That way I can process different enumerations with a generic routine.

```pascal
procedure PopulateComboBox(aComboBox: TMyComboBox; aEnum: ??? );
var
  ArrayEnumLabels: TArray<string>;
  ArrayEnumNames: TArray<aEnum>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ArrayEnumNames  := Enum<aEnum>.AsArray;
  ArrayEnumLabels := Enum<aEnum>.EnumNames;

  aComboBox.ClearItemsValues;
  for i := Enum<aEnum>.MinValue to Enum<aEnum>.MaxValue do begin
    aComboBox.Items.Add(
      ArrayEnumLabels[i]
    );

    aComboBox.Values.Add(
      Enum<aEnum>.ValueName(ArrayEnumNames[i])
    );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This might not have to do with the question directly, but maybe it is usefull for you: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27397

Comment: So use a generic method then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Put the enum into a `TValue` (uses `System.Rtti`) before passing - need to use `TValue.From` (can omit the generic type parameter as type inference works here)
2. Make `PopulateComboBox` generic

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I will try both your suggestion.